Identify this horror movie about an inherited estate
I saw the movie in the 70s or 80s, and it didn't seem too old then. Maybe 50s, 60s or very early 70s. 
In the movie, a woman arrives at an old estate, by a cliff, that she just inherited. It is being looked after by a caretaker, who I believe was a famous horror actor like Boris Karloff or Bela Lugosi.
The caretaker isn't happy she arrived. He is harboring a large hairy monster. They are keeping kidnapped girls chained in a room behind a wall. They are sacrificing the girls on an alter by the cliff. They try to hide it from the new owner, but she discovers the room and she is also chained in the room.
Towards the end, she is rescued and the monster is knocked off the cliff. Details are vague now, but I believe the monster is ape like. 
I really thought the caretaker was Boris Karloff, but now I think it could have been Bela Lugosi, Christopher Lee, Vincent Price or some other equally famous actor as well. 

Why not search the filmographies of these stars?

@John: Read the synopses of 800 movies or ask on M&TV?  Hmmm...

Thanks John.  Unfortunately, I have searched their filmographies dozens of times over the last ten years and no luck.  This is like a last straw.
